# logical error in sorting of array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

**Problem-**
To sort array in such a way that number greater than first element is on right side and less than first element is on left side

**Sample input-**
5
4 5 3 7 2   (Taking 4 as reference)

**Sample output**
3 2 4 5 7
**My code is sorting in this way**
 
**Input**
5
12
16
2
3
56
**output**
2
3
2
3
56

```
int main()
{

   int i,j,n,temp;
   printf("enter no of elements of array");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int a[n];
   printf("enter array\n");
     for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
     {
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
   j=0;
   for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
   {
   if(a[i]<a[j])
     {
     temp=a[j];
     a[j]=a[i];
     a[i]=a[j];
     j++;
     }
   }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  printf("Array is%d\n",a[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You forgot to ask the question..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to read this: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry, there is a logical error in the code it is not sorting the array

Comment: Did you want your output like your sample output?

Comment: Edit your question and write that. Also, what does "with taking reference to first element of the array" mean? Are you supposed to traverse the array using a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
j=0;
for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
    if(a[i]<a[0]){
        temp=a[j+1];
        a[j+1]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
        j++;
    }
}
temp = a[0];
a[0] = a[j];
a[j] = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,

```
 temp=a[j];
 a[j]=a[i];
 a[i]=a[j];
```

should be

```
 temp=a[j];
 a[j]=a[i];
 a[i]=temp;
```

That explains the duplicates. But once you've sorted (ha ha) that out you'll find that it's not quite right as you only compare each number to its neighbour - what if the last number in the array is the smallest? - you'll only move it to one position earlier (e.g. 4th position in a list of 5 numbers).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
{
 if(a[i]<a[j])
 {
 temp=a[j];
 a[j]=a[i];
 a[i]=a[j];// change to a[i]=temp;
 j++;
 }
}
```

In this loop only you tried to sort your array elements. You have to modify your sorting mechanism with correcting your swap function last statement.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in your program you have a `variable length array which isn't valid in standard C.`

```
printf("enter no of elements of array");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

It may work, but if you try to initialize to any value or zero then you may face the following error.

```
[Error] variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

Here for `a[n]` the memory will be allocated on the stack which is not very good for large.
You can only define the length of an array with a constant. (such as)
`int a[10];`